# Return difference between function argument and given number with limited bottom margin

Tags: javascript, algorithm, refactoring, mathematical-optimization, modulo

I have this code (JavaScript) here and it seems like I could refactor it in just one instruction, maybe using modulo (`%`)?
(note: n is always between 0 and 6, no need to deal with other cases)

```
switch (n) {
  case 0: 
    return 1
  case 1:
    return 7
  case 2:
    return 6
  case 3:
    return 5
  case 4:
    return 4
  case 5:
    return 3
  case 6:
    return 2
}
```

I could do:

```
if (n === 0) {
  return 1
} 
return (8 - n)
```

Is there an even shorter way using modulo sign that I could do this?

Comment: What happens if `n` is less than 0 or more than 6?

Comment: It never happens. Sorry should have mentioned it, n is always in [0, 6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the modulo version:

```js
const inputs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function fn(x) {
  return 7 - ((x + 6) % 7);
}

console.log(inputs.map(fn))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Just wondering, what was your reasoning, how did you figure it out?

Comment: I always draw the graph I want on a piece of paper, then come up with the transformations I need. Negating the result for instance will flip the graph along the x-axis. Adding to the result moves it up. Subtracting from x moves it to the right, etc. I assumed that case 7 would return 1, so there's 7 different results. Which means I need `a - ((x + b) % 7)`. Then I tried different values for b until the cutoff was between cases 0 and 1. Finally I adjusted a to get the proper range :)

Answer (score 3):

A bit more tricky one: `return Math.max(8-n, 1)`, which will cover negatives as well

Comment: I think you meant `max`, not `min`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the conditional operator:

```
return n === 0 ? 1 : 8 - n;
```

Comment: Or `n ? 8 - n : 1`

Comment: @ChrisG: I guess, original one is more *type-safe* and robust against inputs, like `n = null` or `n = undefined`